# How to solve dependency in asp.net Could not load type dynamic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage'.?

I have a project (not sure but it's in mvc 2). I have seen project calling mvc 2 dll that is missing with my VS 12 Express installation.

I have tried to download MVc 2 and have installed it. I am not sure but now I got problem something like 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage' could not be loaded.

I have system.web.mvc v3 reference to my project but it's not worked. Do someone know how to get it worked.

I have no issue if I need to convert this project to mvc3. Right now how I can run it.

Thanks

Comment: Please check that you have reference of "System.Web.Mvc" in your application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I make a new project and add my component their. Now when I copy their dll to my project it's work fine.